# Prove or give a counterexample If $a \in \Bbb R$\ $\Bbb Q$ exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $a^n \in \Bbb Q$

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

1)If $a \in \Bbb R$\ $\Bbb Q$  exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $a^n \in \Bbb Q$

2)If $a \in \Bbb R$\ $\Bbb Q$ ,  $_n\sqrt a \in \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q  $  $\forall n \in \Bbb N$

For the second one: [by contradiction]
Let $a \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \Bbb Q $ .

$_n\sqrt a \in \Bbb Q \Rightarrow \exists p \in  \Bbb Z, q \in \Bbb N$ such that $p/q= _n\sqrt a  $

$\Rightarrow {(p/q)}^n = {_n\sqrt a}^n  \Rightarrow p^n/q^n=a \Rightarrow p^n = q^n a $.

As we know the product between irrational and rational is irrational $\Rightarrow p^n $ is irrational. And this is te contradiction because $p \in \Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb Q$. Hence  $_n\sqrt a \in \Bbb R$\ $\Bbb Q$.

Is it correct (or why not)?

Any ideas for the first one?

Comment: You can prove that 1) is false by showing that the number of $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of rational numbers is countable, hence there must be a real number which is not an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of anything in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @avid19 that's not the case: $1+\sqrt{2}$ is not trascendental, but has the property that none of his powers are rational

Comment: @Exodd you are correct

Comment: This question needs to be rephrased to make the meaning of the question clear to average English speaking mathematicians (for whom "exists" in the middle of a statement does not result in a meaningful or well-scoped question and for whom "if" does not constitute a logical quantifer). I think both of your questions are intended to have the form "Is it the case that for all $a \in \ldots$, there exists $n \in \ldots$ such that $\ldots$?" Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed that any real not rational isn't the power of a rational (and that's also obvious since the power of a rational is a rational).
So the 2) is false.

For the 1), take $a=1+\sqrt{2}$. You have that
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}$$
with $a_n>0$, $b_n>0$, so that it's not rational. 
This proves that 1) is false

Answer (score 0):

1) take any transcendental all powers are not integers by definition eg $\pi.$

2) if $x^{1/n}=q$ is rational then 
$$
x= (x^{1/n})^n = q^n \in {\Bbb Q} 
$$
so 2 is false.